# Access window object in ember-cli environment

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Hi I am trying to use torii in a cordova application. My environment.js file looks as below. I an not able to access window document object to setup redirectUri. getting error undefined variable. how can I access window document object.

```
module.exports = function (environment) {
    var ENV = {
        environment: environment,
        baseURL: '/',
        locationType: 'hash',
        EmberENV: {
            FEATURES: {
                // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
                // e.g. 'with-controller': true
            }
        },
        APP: {
            // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
            // when it is created
        },
        torii: {
            providers: {
                'facebook-oauth2': {
                    apiKey: '2xxxxxxxxxx',
                    redirectUri: document.location.href
                },
            }
        },
        cordova: {
            rebuildOnChange: false,
            rebuildAsync: false,
            emulate: false
        }
    };
```

in my .jshintrc

```
"predef": {
    "document": true,
    "window": true,
    "AuthENV": true
  }
```

so I assume document should be globally available but it is not

Comment: how are you trying to use the `window` and `document` objects - can you provide a sample?

Comment: redirectUri: document.location.href //here

Answer (score 1):

You are able to access the `window` and `document` object through most of your Ember.js code as global variables.

In this particular file, you are trying to access it in use for the app config. The problem is that the config is generated during the Node.js build process - meaning that the context is not the same.

You will see in the page source of your app that the config is static and serialized into a meta property in the page:

```
<meta name="[your-app]/config/environment" content="your-config-here" />
```

As the redirect url will change dynamically depending on the user's location, it would be easier to pull in this data "just in time" for the OAuth flow.