# Javascript objects in ember-cli config/environment

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

In my config/environment file, I'd like to include a `Date` object.

Doing the following:

```
module.exports = function(environment){
  var ENV = {
    ...     
    APP: {
      someDate = new Date(2014, 12, 25, 22, 0, 0, 0),
      ....
    }
    ....
  };
  ...
};
```

And accessing it via:

```
import ENV from 'my-app/config/environment';

...

var isDate = ENV.APP.someDate instanceof Date; //false
var isDateFromWin = window.MyAppENV.APP.someDate instanceof Date; //false
```

Results pulled from config object are of type string, and not a date object. Are settings in the environments file always returned as strings? How can I return a date (or other POJO) from my config file?

Additionally, the file seems to be ignoring my `.jshintrc` file, and am unable to access the `window` object as per [Access window object in ember-cli environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609303/access-window-object-in-ember-cli-environment)

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the "doing the following" example, it should be:

```
...     
APP: {
  someDate: new Date(2014, 12, 25, 22, 0, 0, 0),
  ...
}
...
```

Also, you should access it like:

```
date = MyAppENV.APP.someDate; // replace with name of your entry point
```

or:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
date = Ember.ENV.APP.someDate;
```

Comment: Ah, that's a typo in my example, sorry! my dates are still coming through as strings regardless of whether I pull them from the window object or import them. Although there's no Ember.ENV.APP available to me. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

All the environment config values are getting encoded before being rendered to the `<meta>` tag in your result **index.html**. You can check your generated environment config in the **dist/index.html** and see how it looks like.

It means that when you import environment config in your js you get decoded strings. That's why you loose a type date.

If you need to pass a date I would propose to set timestamp to your environment config